# How can i put my divs right next to each (vertically) others without overlapping?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overlapping

My divs are overlapping here's the code of my index.html :

```css
.titlesec {

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
}

#moi {

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 107px 70px 0 70px;
  height: 80vh;
}

.nom h1 {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 130px;
}

.intro {

  margin-top: 150px;
  width: 50%;
  align-self: flex-end;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-size: 23px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="moi">
        <div class="nom reveal-">
            <h1>Maxime Miquel</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="intro reveal-2" >
            <p >some text no one cares about</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="one" class="titlesec reveal-2">
        <h1>TITLE</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="formation">
       .........
    </div>
```

And the result : [Image in a browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTJ2z.jpg)

The title is overlapping the div right on top of it when i reduce the viewheight. This problem appeared when i changed the height of #moi to 80vh.

Hope someone can help me. Thank you =)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the flex box containers or you can use the css grid to make two columns.

grid-area: item1, item2
item1, item2;

Comment: Hi, We are always happy to welcome new member in our SO community, you know your answer could make a history with some few modifications : always try to include `code snippet` in support of your answer, explaining why and how your answer works with examples will make your answer more attractive and easy for newcomers, TIP : it is a good idea to include [source links](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) like [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)